# Calculated angles from three sides only show either 90 or 180 degrees

Tags: java

This is the problem: Write a program that prompts for the lengths of the sides of a triangle and reports the three angles.

I have written the following code for it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Please input length of side A: ");
    int sideA = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please input length of side B: ");
    int sideB = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please input length of side C: ");
    int sideC = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The angle between A and B is: " + calculateAngle(sideA, sideB, sideC));
    System.out.println("The angle between B and C is: " + calculateAngle(sideB, sideC, sideA));
    System.out.println("The angle between C and A is: " + calculateAngle(sideC, sideA, sideB));     
}
    
    public static double calculateAngle(int a, int b, int c) {
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a * b)));
    }
```

Here is a sample output from my code above:

```
Please input length of side A: 55
Please input length of side B: 22
Please input length of side C: 76

The angle between A and B is: 90.0
The angle between B and C is: 90.0
The angle between C and A is: 90.0
```

No matter what values I input for the sides, the only angles I ever get are 90 or 180 degrees, never the actual correct angle that can be calculated from the cosine rule. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: To clarify @Aplet123 comment - integer division means the `acos` in your calculation is always being given zero which is 90 degrees.  Change the variables to `float` or `double`, or cast the result in the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation they are expecting a double value as their parameter for `acos` method [JavaSE7 Math doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#acos(double))

so re-arrange your code like this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please input length of side A: ");
        double sideA = console.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Please input length of side B: ");
        double sideB = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please input length of side C: ");
        double sideC = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The angle between A and B is: " + calculateAngle(sideA, sideB, sideC));
        System.out.println("The angle between B and C is: " + calculateAngle(sideB, sideC, sideA));
        System.out.println("The angle between C and A is: " + calculateAngle(sideC, sideA, sideB));
    }

    public static double calculateAngle(double a, double b, double c) {
        return Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a * b)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the calculation in `Math.acos` to `double` :

```
return Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((double)(a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a * b)));
```

As you could see in comments, when computing between multiple `int` types, the `integer` arithmetic is used and then casted to `double`.

Also it's worth noting, that `int` always round down, meaning:

```
int i = 0.9999999;  // i = 0
```